# How can I browse a folder currently open in nautilus in the terminal?

Tags: nautilus, command-line, filemanager

I would like to be able to to this easily, in all of the following ways:

- Keyboard shortcut
- Right-click
- Drag a folder into an open terminal (with a certain mouse button)
- Drag the title bar into an open terminal (with a certain mouse button)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the package `nautilus-open-terminal` that provides a new context menu item in Nautilus to open the current folder in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Nautilus Terminal](http://projects.flogisoft.com/nautilus-terminal/).  It essentially creates a mini-terminal window in each Nautilus window.  Comes in handy often.